# How to fix position of Y-axis on c3 grouped bar chart?

Tags: javascript, css, c3.js

[Here is my output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK28Z.png).I have a grouped bar chart in C3. I have scroll with x-axis with respect to data. While scrolling x-axis my y axis moves along with. How to fix position of y-axis fixed on screen.Since I have to represent large number of data so I want scroll on x-axis and Y-axis need to be fixed and bar width need to same as previous because as number of data increases bar width gets automatically decreases.
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.3/c3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.5.0/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.3/c3.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function () {
var months = ['Jan 2016', 'Feb2016', 'Feb2016','Jan 2016', 'Feb2016', 'Feb2016'];
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        bindto: '#chart',
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100,30, 200, 100],
            ['data2', 130, 100, 140,30, 200, 100 ]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
   bar: {
  width: {
    ratio: 0.6
  }
},
    axis: { 
    x: {
    type: 'category',
    categories: months,
     label: {
              text: 'open cases',
              position: 'outer-middle'
            }
  },
   y: {
            label: {
              text: 'open cases',
              position: 'outer-middle'
            }
          }


  },

});
});


</script>
<style>
svg
{
width:400px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:300px;overflow-x:auto">
<div id="chart" ></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tryed so far?

Comment: Did you figured out something? I'm facing the same problem.